# Insecure Login Blocked. Try re-loading the page as https://

Tags: wordpress, facebook, authentication, plugins

I'm using OneAll social login WordPress plugin.

I have a problem when logging into my WordPress site.
https://www.screencast.com/t/Nk0PyhgowNA

"Insecure Login Blocked. Try reloading the page as https://."
I've tried to disable Enforce HTTPS for Web OAuth Login on the Facebook app developer setting. But the toggle button is disabled.
https://www.screencast.com/t/TAhTYf2ojwmi

I have checked on the social plugin setup and API setting on my account.
https://www.screencast.com/t/NBhDoClM0hGH
https://www.screencast.com/t/5nQXZlwT4
All links redirect to HTTPS.

But why on the login button still go to 'http://', not redirect to https://?
https://www.screencast.com/t/Ehlx6wnIsvF

My website: http://www.kbknews.id

Comment: When did you create your app? _“All new apps created as of March 2018 have this setting on by default and you should plan to migrate any existing apps to use only HTTPS URLs by March 2019.”_ Plus, Chrome is planning to mark all non-HTTPS sites as “insecure” soon (Chrome 68, will be released in July 2018), so you might want to switch to HTTPS rather sooner than later.

Comment: @CBroe what about localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because according to new rule of facebook app, you must have a secure site from where you want to login so you need to get a secure certificate for youe website, after that you can do login with facebook.
Hope its helpful...
Good Luck..